# Input string is not in correct format ternary operator using in grid view .

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, operators

i am using this ternary operator for the display the value but it always says that Input string is not in correct format .

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtPerOfBase" runat="server" Style="text-align: right;" Text='<%# decimal.Parse(Eval("CommissionableAmountBase").ToString()) == 0 ? Eval("CommissionablePercentBase","{0:N2}"): Eval("CommissionableAmountBase","{0:N2)")%>'
                                                                        Width="80px"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Is the `#` right after `<%` causing the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here:

```
Eval("CommissionableAmountBase","{0:N2)")
```

it should be `}` right after N2

```
Eval("CommissionableAmountBase","{0:N2}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Silly mistakes, replace your entire code which you had shown here, with following

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPerOfBase" runat="server" Style="text-align: right;" 
Text='<%#   decimal.Parse(Eval("CommissionableAmountBase").ToString()) == 0 ?  Eval("CommissionablePercentBase","{0:N2}"): Eval("CommissionableAmountBase","{0:N2}")%>'
Width="80px">
</asp:TextBox>
```

You had use **)** instead of **}**. This is your mistake...